# Why does a return statement in a finally block negates raise in the except block?

Tags: python, exception

In my Python script I would like to catch an exception, perform some cleanup operations, and `raise` the exception again. Since the cleanup is common for both the success and failure paths, I tried putting it in the `finally` block. However, when I add a `return` statement inside the `finally` block, the `raise` is negated.

Here is an example (I am using Python 3.6.5):

```py
def test():
    try:
        raise Exception('TEST')
    except:
        raise
    finally:
        print('FINALLY!')
        return ''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
    print('SHOULD NOT REACH THIS LINE!')
```

Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: Because `finally` is final.  If you want to return only if the `try` block succeeded, that's what an `else` block is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is addressed directly in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions).

On one side:

> - An exception could occur during execution of an `except` or `else` clause. Again, the exception is re-raised after the `finally` clause
>   has been executed.

***BUT***:

> - If the `finally` clause executes a [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break), [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue) or [**`return`**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#return) statement, **exceptions are not re-raised**.